# How do I add a plot line at a position that exists to the left of the x axis in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have a graph that looks like [this]([image]).You'll notice that the plotline that I've added along the y axis is at the '0' location. I need the line to be to the left of the rest of the xAxis data like [this]([image]), so that the line doesn't go through the first set of points.

The problem is, the addPlotline function doesn't take negative values. I tried
this.xAxis[0].addPlotLine(
{
value: -10
}
);

to put the plotline there. However, since it doesn't take negative values, it ended up working exactly the same as

this.xAxis[0].addPlotLine(
{
value: 0
}
);
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your use case, you can change the range of the xAxis.

Example:

```
 let chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
   xAxis: {
     type: 'datetime'
   },
   series: [{
     data: [1,2,3,4]
   }]

 });

 btn1.addEventListener('click', () => {
   chart.update({
     xAxis: {
       min: -0.5
     }
   })
   chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
     value: -0.5,
     color: 'red',
     width: 2,
     id: 'first'
   })
 });
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9y0acfxz/